# IDAPython Decompile - connect assembly to pseudo-code line

Tags: ida, decompilation, idapython

I'm trying to write a small application that can show for each
line of the de-compiled psuedo code of a certain function
the assembly instruction that responsible for it.

for example if we have a function invocation in the pseudo code - i want to show all the push to stack instructions + the call instruction:

```
sample_function(a,b)

//will be mapped to:

push b
push a
call sample_function
```

I've tried to scan the objects that are returned by the [decompile](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_hexrays-module.html#decompile) method and gone through some examples: [vds1](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/vds1.py), [vds4](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/vds4.py), ... Haven't found a solution.

Is this mapping is saved somewhere? In IDA i can access the other direction when it shows in the assembly the pseudo code as comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: There is a disassembly option in VS 2019. Not ideal, but pretty close. You can jump in and out assembly code while debugging.